# Get 'unknow host' from ubuntu container in docker stack

Tags: docker, ubuntu, lookup, hostname, swarm

I run `ping` in Ubuntu:18.04.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y inetutils-ping
```

Run `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test` to test the command `ping`

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
networks:
  test:
services:
  stack:
    image: my_ubuntu:1.0.0
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: any

    networks:
      - test
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        ping stack
```

I run the command `docker service logs -f test_stack` to get the logs:

```
ping: unknow host
ping: unknow host
ping: unknow host
ping: unknow host
...
about 5 minutes later
ping is successful
```

But, if I use `docker-compose` to start it, `ping` is successful.

For comparison, I also run `ping` in alpine, `ping` is successful.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
networks:
  test:
services:
  stack:
    image: alpine:3.7
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: any

    networks:
      - test
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        ping stack
```

Does anybody know the reason, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What command do you use to launch it in the case where it doesn't work?

Comment: @DavidMaze Run command `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test` to launch it